# Connecting from windows phone 7 to MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I am trying to connect a windows phone 7 app to MySQL database at a PC.

From what I found out after lots of searching, there is no direct way to do so. There is a lot of people saying restsharp could help communicating, but there seems to be very few info regarding the success and ways to do so.

I need to get the wp7 app to send data into MySQL db, so a website could take the data sent into the db and display it out.

Any kind people willing to give me some guidance or direct me to a known guide?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Typical way to do it is to setup your own website (better to be password protected, and over SSL). Then you use REST or simply HTTP POST to pass the data to your web scripts, which in turn connect to MySQL and do actual data INSERT.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you explain more on how I pass the data to the web using a wp7 app? Treat me as a newbie.

Comment: Take a look to WebClient and Webrequest :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: WebClient and Webrequest is for the wp7 part?
How about the API or URI, do you know any known guide?